# linq2db update cannot find definition for .Set method MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, orm, linq2db

I am implementing linq2db in my project, currently I am trying to carry out an update but I am stuck on this issue. Now I can see there is no extension method in the class available, however in the demo on github and in the source I can't seem to find anything different from what I am doing. So not sure how to do this.

error:
[image: Error]

Table:
[image: Table]

Comment: Can you copy and paste to your answer how you're creating the "context" which implements `LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection`. Please copy and paste the full class here.

Comment: It won't let me paste it, as its too big for the answer and question body

Comment: check the below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `using LinqToDB;` at the top of your class.

This syntax works:

Two lambdas **one for the property selector** and second for the **value**.

```
db.Product.Where(x => x.ProductID == 1).Set(x => x.Name, x => "ABC");
```

You are going to face a hard time with `IntelliSense` using this method, unless you right two empty lambadas `Set(x=> ,  x=>)`, then `IntelliSense` shows up.

Comment: this doesn't work, because it still can't find the .Set extension method, thats the issue...

Comment: @Harry Do you have `using LinqToDB;` at the top of your class ?

Comment: ahh dude! that's what it was. I was using LinqToDB.Mappings instead!